# mysql java connection error

Tags: java, mysql, connection, classnotfound

I am running my JAR file in linux (centos). All jar files work fine.

Now i am trying to connect to mysql server, but it gave me following
error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I don't have server root access. I have a simple user account. I downloaded mysql.jar
file for db connection, and put that in lib folder. Jar file contains lib path in .CLASSPATH file.

### EDIT

I am running Jar file at command line

java -jar prog.jar

Comment: could you please tell us how you are trying to run the program? From command line, from eclipse, etc?

Comment: Thanks. I have added an answer. Please let us know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `java -cp path\to\your\mysql.jar -jar prog.jar`

Comment: Is the mysql.jar same as the connector.jar? I did a google on this class name and it looks it's in the connector jar. Could you please download this and extract the jar file from the zip? http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html

Comment: Also another way to verify if this class exists in mysql.jar is running this command jar tf mysql.jar . Could you please check com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class shows up in that list?

Comment: Hi, thanks for explaining. All the required classes are there. It works fine inside the window/eclipse. As soon as i export as jar and run on linux it creates problems. I am using mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar

Comment: Alright. Did you rename `mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar`  to `mysql.jar`? Secondly, how did you export the jar file from eclipse? What options did you pick?

Comment: no i did not renamed jar file. Now I renamed it to mysql.jar and run again but same error. I exported with default options.

Comment: So this time you ran java -cp \path\to\your\mysql.jar -jar prog.jar ? You can't be getting the same class not found exception if your path to mysql.jar is correct.

Answer (score 0):

To run the application from the command line you need to specify the CLASSPATH as a command line argument:

```
java -cp mysql.jar -jar prog.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

The .CLASSPATH file is an eclipse project file which will not be used when executing from the command line. Try following [this guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html) to set your classpath.